# How to create a Docker image with Ubuntu 14.04 x86 architecture?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, x86, 64-bit

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
From i386/ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git cmake ..... and other packages
```

I created image using this Dockerfile and launched container from this image,
and inside container I entered command `uname -m` and it gives this output:

```
x86_64
```

So it means, that I have Ubuntu 14.04 x64. Why do I have x64 Ubuntu instead of x86? I need x86.

Comment: I guess that `68` is your architecture and `64` is the size of the data units that are processed per instruction. As far as I know they are independent features of a CPU. So if you "need x86", the answer seems to me that you have x86 already.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a 32-bit userspace with a 64-bit kernel.  You almost always want a 64-bit kernel, even for a purely 32-bit user-space.  Especially if your (virtual) machine has more than 1GB of RAM, because a 32-bit kernel has to use HIGHMEM / PAE hacks and can't just map it all.  i.e. i386 Ubuntu may still install an x86-64 kernel, and this is what `uname` is showing you.

Use `file /bin/ls` to see if your system binaries are `ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386` or `ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64`.

---

On a more recent distro, you might see `ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64` if it builds packages with position-independent executables (PIE) enabled by default.  Hopefully distros aren't doing this for 32-bit code, because PIC/PIE has measurable performance overhead in 32-bit mode, where RIP-relative addressing modes aren't available.  Although distros do ship gcc configured with `--enable-default-pie`, and that does apply to `-m32` [unless you turn it off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux).  Anyway, PIE executables can use ASLR for the executable, not just for shared libraries, so there's a security advantage for a very small performance cost (in 64-bit code).

Comment: This maybe should have been a comment.  I posted it as an answer because it got too big for a comment.  I think i386 Ubuntu doesn't default to an x86-64 kernel, but I'm pretty certainly there is one available in the i386 repo.